# Summarize each category of rows in one column using R

Tags: r, summary

I'm wondering if this is something possible in R:
I have 2 columns. `Column A (primaryhistory2.DEPT)` has a bunch of categorical data, `column B (primaryhistry2.ACT.ENROLL)` has numbers and `NAs`.
[image: looks like this]

I want to get a summary of column B for each category in column A.
Something like, for "NUT" in column A, I want to see `min`, `max`, `mean`, `median`, `NAs`, etc. And I would like to see this for every category. Like when you use `summary()` command.

Not sure if this is possible.. Thank you all in advance!

@Moody_Mudskipper 
The results are what I'm looking for. But without column names it's hard to read.
[image]

and for the base R, it's not doing counts for NAs, which I do see a lot of NAs in my file.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very possible using `dplyr` library:

```
library(dplyr)
most.of.the.answer = df %>% 
    group_by(primaryhistory2.DEPT) %>%
    summarise(min = min(primaryhistry2.ACT.ENROLL, na.rm = TRUE), max = max(primaryhistry2.ACT.ENROLL, na.rm = TRUE), mean = mean(primaryhistry2.ACT.ENROLL, na.rm = TRUE), median = median(primaryhistry2.ACT.ENROLL, na.rm = TRUE))
```

(assuming your dataframe is called `df`)

For counting NA's, try `dplyr`'s `filter` feature:

```
count.NAs = df %>% filter(is.na(primaryhistry2.ACT.ENROLL)) %>%
    group_by(primaryhistory2.DEPT) %>%
    summarise(count.NA = n())
```

I'll leave it to you to merge the two dataframes.

Comment: you might need to add na.rm = T on each of the statistics, otherwise you will get NAs.

Comment: Thanks.  For counting NA's, all I can think of is to do a separate dataframe and merge later.  I'll edit my question

Comment: I added the sum(is.na()) myself and it's working perfectly! Exactly what I wanted! Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

with base R you can do this:

```
temp <- aggregate(primaryhistory2..ACT.ENROLL ~ primaryhistory2.DEPT,df,function(x){c(mean = mean(x,na.rm=T),median = median(x,na.rm=T),min = min(x,na.rm=T),max = max(x,na.rm=T),nas=sum(is.na(x)))})
res <- cbind(temp[1],temp[[2]])
```

If you want to use `summary`:

```
summary1 <- sapply(unique(df$primaryhistory2.DEPT),function(x) summary(subset(df,primaryhistory2.DEPT == x)$primaryhistory2..ACT.ENROLL))
colnames(summary1) <- unique(df$primaryhistory2.DEPT)
```

Comment: Hi, the summary one works perfectly!! Just the column names don't show,the error says "Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c(17L, 33L, 62L, 43L, 68L, 20L,  : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions"

Comment: you should replace your screen capture with the result of `dput(head(df,50))`

Comment: I see, `sapply` returns a matrix only if all vectors have same length, and it's not the case as you probably don't have NAs for each variable

Comment: Is there a way to get the count of NAs in base R? Or is there a way to add a name for each summary?

Comment: I'll just give you a super dirty way for now because i have to go, `summary(c(subset(df,primaryhistory2.DEPT == x)$primaryhistory2..ACT.ENROLL,NA))` and then substract 1 from the last column of results

Comment: ps: there is no `na.rm` in `is.na` call